# Creating socket inside a SQL-CLR trigger or stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, sqlclr

I have a SQL-CLR trigger in SQL Server 2008 that sends out message to socket server. It works fine but I need the TCP client to stay connected to the server it communicates with.

In order to do this I have to make some thread that stays alive. So I created a thread added the message to queue, I see client connecting but SQL Server kicks out before the client is able to process the queued message and send it to tcp server.

The purpose of this application is to send what fields and some values associated to them that were updated via xml.  I wanted to put them in queue that gets handled in thread and send to TCP Socket Server.

What I am planning as alternative now is have CLR Trigger add messages to MSMQ and have another service to process these messages.

Any good suggestions how to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you be more specific on what type of server you communicate with? How much data you will send, for what purpose and what protocol? (Logging information? Message Queuing? Game server communication?)

Comment: I update my question to have this detail.  I want to send modified column/value association for the table at hand in some xml format.  So my goal is to store this data in queue and processing them one at a time.  The socket client hopefully to have only one connection to server since there are a lot of changes on that table.

Comment: HAve you looked into using Service Broker?

Comment: I am using SQL Server Express only which does not have this feature

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with a trigger instead of building it into your main app?

Comment: I need to know what data was changed without polling for it.

Comment: This is what message queues were designed for.

Comment: @Dmitry, why don't you record the information you need on a regular table and then let the consumers read it? RDMS already implement and solve many communication issues that you will have to deal working directly with sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CREATE ASSEMBLY Messaging
AUTHORIZATION dbo
FROM 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Messaging.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO