# Can you place a listener on a db table or similar

Tags: java, spring, listener

I have a java backend system. We need integrate to a third party. I need to return results to a client. Currently we are using a view (SQL SERVER) that the third party write to and keep a tracker of the unique id somewhere.

I have a Spring-wired poller that runs every 10min that will return everything from what was last sent to end and update the tracker table with the new ID. Nothing complicated.

I would like to know if there is a simple way to almost "listen" on the table. If any new rows are added, grab them and return them via my service. And if there is, is it advisable?

Comment: The 3rd party is writing directly to the DB?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Yes they are, it is their db. We are allowed to read from their views and only write to some staging tables from which they do batch processing. They use MS Sql Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use triggers on the view, but that won't help in java land as most DBs aren't going to let you run java code there.  Your choices are: 1) polling like you are doing or 2) create a web service (or JMS queue or something) that the third party calls to push the update/insert of data.  Then you are in java land and Hibernate/Spring can handle the insert and do whatever processing you need.

Comment: I'll accept this answer because it basically confirmed my current implementation. I was hoping that there was something out there that I didn't know about. So the third party has a product. They will not write something specifically for us, so the webservice call is out. Even though that is what we wanted in the first place. I also don't have much rights on the db for triggers like the rest suggested. We can only interrogate their data and write to certain tables (for staging). So for now, I'll stick with the pollers.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have not exactly done this, yet, and SQL Server is not my playground. However, combining triggers with non-SQL commands should be possible nowadays, and searching the internet for 'sql server notification' yields a section on 'Query Notifications in SQL Server':
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2(v=vs.110).aspx

In general, as long as it is possible to somehow send a command to a socket from inside a trigger then you could use a PUB-SUB message queue (RabbitMQ, NSQ etc.) to send a notification that you can retrieve in your Java program. Of course, you would have to install triggers on any columns that you want to monitor. Whether it is possible to monitor a schema (or database) for changes in general - this might only be possible if there is some logging inside the database that you have access to. This might not be there, out of the box. The trigger is probably the cleaner way because it resides in the schema/database itself and does not need to access system tables.

EDIT: also found this SO question/answer about socket connection inside a trigger: [Creating socket inside a SQL-CLR trigger or stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236288/creating-socket-inside-a-sql-clr-trigger-or-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

You could use triggers on the tables, if performance is not an issue